# A better way to retrieve a part of string with groovy

Tags: regex, groovy

I have a list of file names like this:

```
"XX111NO_1_myText.txt"
"AABBBAAABBB_25_myHtml.html"
"VVHHY_6_myLog.log"
```

I want to retrieve only a specific part of these string to have:

```
"myText"
"myHtml"
"myLog"
```

I implemented this code and its work:

```
def fileName = "XX111NO_1_myText.txt"

fileName = fileName.substring( fileName.lastIndexOf(fileName.find(/_[1-9]+_/))+fileName.find(/_[1-9]+_/).length() , fileName.lastIndexOf(".") ) 

assert fileName == "myText"
```

Is there a better way to perform this task? For example using only regex

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a regular expression:

```
def names = [ "XX111NO_1_myText.txt",
              "AABBBAAABBB_25_myHtml.html",
              "VVHHY_6_myLog.log",
              "bad.data" ]

def matches = names.collect {
    ( it =~ /^.+_(\S+)\.\S+$/ ).with { m ->
        m.matches() ? m[ 0 ][ 1 ] : null
    }
}

assert matches == [ 'myText', 'myHtml', 'myLog', null ]
```

Comment: That basically looks for the start of a line `^` followed by some characters `.+`, followed by an underscore `_` followed by some non-whitespace characters (that we want to capture) `(\S+)` followed by a dot `\.` followed by some non-whitespace characters `\S+` followed by the end of the line `$`

Comment: I changed a little bit your pattern /^.+_[1-9]+_(\S+)\.\S+$/.
to avoid matching a file name like: "XXX.XXXX_13.XXXX.txt"

Comment: @Jils Maybe: `/^.+_[0-9]+_(\S+)\.\S+$/` (allow `0` in the numbers too)